# Postfix - How to process inbound emails?

Tags: postfix

I am building web application where users add new content by sending emails to application. 
Email address used for each user is custom (eg. 123456@myservice.com) and it is dynamically created as a Postfix virtual mailbox.

User needs to be able to send email to his custom mailbox address (as12145ed@myservice.com) and i want to process each incoming email, parse it's contents and populate my database with data from email.

I tried using [Postfix After Queue filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html) but what i really want is to process emails once they are saved in user's virtual mailbox folder.

Answer (score 6):

I would take another approach to this.

Instead of creating individual mailboxes, I would create one catchall address and then via /etc/aliases send that to a script in which I would do all my parsing and archiving. There is no reason to use mailboxes when you are not going to store e-mail in them, it's a huge overhead.

In /etc/aliases you could make this entry

```
usermail: "|/path/to/myscript.pl"
```

and then all e-mail would be sent directly to myscript.pl and you can handle it in there.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two possible solutions to this:

**First possibility**: You can set a custom `mailbox_command` in Postfix. For each email Postfix receives, it will call the `mailbox_command` defined in the configuration file and provide the email as plain text on `stdin`. That way, you can decide how you want to process each email. You will have to parse the headers of the email yourself though. You can take a look at the [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mailbox_command) for more of an idea on how to make this work. Additional applications like `procmail` can also act as a `mailbox_command` and help you with processing the incoming mails.

**Second possibility**: Use Dovecot to store emails. You don't need to enable the POP/IMAP modules of Dovecot. However, Dovecot comes with the fantastic `doveadm` utility which allows you to query mailboxes and read from them. With `doveadm`, you can automatically select new emails, emails from last week, read the whole email, just part of it, delete old messages, and so forth. It's a powerful utility, I use it in various scripts to purge old emails or provide `learn-as-spam` folders for users. Take a look at [the documentation](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm) in the wiki.

(Note: I also posted this on Stackoverflow, where the poster asked the same question)

Answer (score 2):

There is a program called *procmail* (an LDA) that will do almost exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would poll the mailboxes using POP3/IMAP, download the messages and process them (rather than try to integrate something into the Postfix stack).  This will also give you a level of fault-tolerance if your parsing system breaks or needs to be taken offline for a window of time.